# How to update React Native hosted view component from native android

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

I'm trying to build WebRTC React Native component library for android. This is my view component code in kotlin side.

> Note: Please try to notice TODO comment.

```
override fun createViewInstance(reactContext: ThemedReactContext): View {
    videoView = SurfaceViewRenderer(reactContext)
    videoView.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT)
    videoView.init(eglBaseContext, object: RendererCommon.RendererEvents {
      override fun onFirstFrameRendered() {}
      override fun onFrameResolutionChanged(width: Int, height: Int, rotation: Int) {
        Log.i(TAG, "$streamName videoWidth: $width, videoHeight: $height")
        // TODO: update react native hosted view
      }
    })

    // Set layout parameters for videoView
    videoView.layoutParams = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      Gravity.CENTER
    )

    container = FrameLayout(reactContext)
    container.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
    container.addView(videoView)

    return container
  }
```

When rendering video streams in this view, the video content doesn't fit properly; it appears too large and gets clipped. Here's how I update the React Native hosted view on the JavaScript side to address this issue.

```
  const [props, set_props] = useState({width: '101%', height: 200});

  setTimeout(() => {
    set_props({width: '100%', height: 200});
  }, 1000);

  // RTCView is native view from above kotlin code.
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello oki dokii</Text>
      { local_peer && <RTCView peerName={local_peer} style={props} /> }
      {
        feeds.map(feed => (
          <RTCView
            key={feed}
            peerName={feed}
            style={props} />
        ))
      }
    </View>
  );
```

One second after rendering the view, I modified its size and re-rendered the React Native component. Then suddenly video content fits in the view. This is not ideal solution. I tried to update React Native view from kotlin side and wasted whole day and night... I can't even ask questions from react native developers in github issue... So that's why I'm asking here to help.